# Best Database for Node js Web App and simple data structure

Tags: node.js, database, non-relational-database

I am planning to make this relatively simple, single-task web-app that is node js based and need help with chosing the best database for my application stack - a field where I have only limited theoretical knowledge and almost no practical experience.

**Usage:** The user of the web-app fills out a simple form at the front-end and according to that information a database-query is formed on the server, some calculations made and the result is returned to the user at the front-end - that's it.

- **User input never changes database** - the database from user
  perspective is read-only.
- **Data structure is very simple** -> "columns" of "timestamp -
  numeric value"-entries.
- **No relations** (other than the "column-relation") between sets, other than that the entries from a specific "column" will always be read out in    sequence (as the calculationsspan over a certain time-period).
- **New data** is only appended to the database once a day (one entry per "column"), existing
  entries will never be changed.
- **Data amount:** 10 - 20 columns with 2000 - 4000 " timestamp - numeric value "- data entries.

**Which database would work best for that project?**

I read quite a bit about the differences, pros and cons of relational and non-relational databases, but I have too little experience to tell which is suited. Somehow I sense that non-relational is the solution. Basically, what I have as data could be put in and read from an excel sheet, but I hear that's just not how you do it.
**MongoDB** seems to be popular in combination with node js but then lots of authors state that it loses data over time, which sounds scary. Some authors go as far as to call it a hype and recommend against using it at all.

Thank you!

Comment: if you chose to down-vote the question, it would be helpful let everybody know why you do it. That will help get better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, motivated by the negative response to my question and lack of answers, I realize that **there is probably no need for an external database at all**.

The amount of data will not exceed 500KB - 5MB and can be handled in memory at all times. Using an external database for this task seems like a huge overkill.
I'm shifting focus now towards finding best data-structure in node-js to handle the data.

I'd still appreciate any thoughts on this.